# How do I put second element of right div to bottom of all on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layer

I use bootstrap to design my website. And I try to do like below motion with layouts. How can I do this?

when size is big;

```
-------------------------
|    A(md-8)   |  B(4)  |
|              |--------|
|              |  C(4)  |
|              |--------|
|              |
----------------
```

when size is small;

```
----------------
|     B        |
----------------
|     A        |
----------------
|     C        |
----------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML put the divs in order B,A,C and give a class say `pull-right-lg` to B and C for floating it right. Target this class only for large devices using media queries.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right-lg">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 pull-right-lg">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .pull-right-lg {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/t4nkjt3r/1/)

Comment: with this solution, when screen is big and length of B longer than A, C is setting position to below of B. how can put C to below of B?(B and C will be as at same sidebar - under to under) thank for your answer.

Comment: Aah got what you meant. You need to give `clear:both` to div C.

Comment: I will get back with the solution. I got what you meant.